# Apply styles to specific cells in Pandas Multindex Dataframe based on value comparison

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, multi-index, pandas-styles

I have a pandas multindex dataframe that looks something like this:

```
in [1] 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

iterables = [['Chemistry', 'Math', 'English'],['Semester_1', 'Semester_2']]
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables)
index = ['Gabby', 'Sam', 'Eric', 'Joe']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(50, 100, (len(index), len(columns))), index=index, columns=columns)
df

out[1]
   Chemistry                  Math               English
  Semester_1 Semester_2 Semester_1 Semester_2 Semester_1 Semester_2
Gabby    86         80         63         50         87         75
Sam      57         84         91         84         60         87
Eric     67         64         52         96         84         70
Joe      51         68         74         69         85         86
```

I am trying to see if there were students who's grades dropped in more than 10 points in the last  semester, color the cells containing the bad grade red and export the whole table to excel. For example, Gabby's Math grade in the second semester dropped 13 points, so I would like the cell containing "50" to be colored red.
[Here is the full output I'm expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ravEc.png).

I have tried the following:

```
def color_values(row):
    change = row['Semester_1'] - row['Semester_2']
    color = 'red' if change > 10 else ''
    return 'color: ' + color

for subject in ['English', 'Algebra', 'Geometry']:
    df = df.style.apply(color_values, axis=1, subset=[subject])
```

However I'm getting the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-e83756bce6ef> in <module>
      1 for subject in ['English', 'Algebra', 'Geometry']:
----> 2     df = df.style.apply(color_values, axis=1, subset=[subject])

AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'style'
```

I cannot figure out a way to do this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

in your first loop when `subject` is "English" you are setting `df` to be a `Styler` object, e.g. `df.style`.

The in your second loop you are calling `.style` on `df` which you set as a `Styler` object, hence the AttributeError.

```
styler = df.style
for subject in ['English', 'Algebra', 'Geometry']:
    styler.apply(color_values, axis=1, subset=[subject])
```